# Error: Shapes (1,4) and (14,14) not aligned

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I'm a newbie to Machine Learning and a little baffled by this error:

Shapes (1,4) and (14,14) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 14 (dim 0)

Here is the full error:

File "/Users/jim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 140, in safe_sparse_dot
    return np.dot(a, b)

ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (14,14) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 14 (dim 0)

My test set has 4 rows of data and training set 14 rows of data, as indicated by (1,4) and (14,14). At least I think that's what that means.

I'm trying to fit a simple linear regression to a Training set as indicated by my code below:

```
# Fit Simple Linear Regression to Training Set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
X_train = X_train.reshape(1,-1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(1,-1)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then predict the Test Set Results:

```
# Predicting the Test Set Results
X_test = X_test.reshape(1,-1)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

My code is failing on the last line with the above error:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Any hints in the right direction would be great.

Here is my whole code sample:

```
# Simple Linear Regression

# Import Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Import dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('NBA.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values

# Splitting the dataset into Train and Test
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
# None

# Fit Simple Linear Regression to Training Set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
X_train = X_train.reshape(1,-1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(1,-1)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test Set Results
X_test = X_test.reshape(1,-1)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

** EDIT **
I checked the shape of X and y. Here is my output below:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('NBA.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
-->(18,)
-->(18, 1)
```

Comment: `reshape(1,-1)` seems to be dangerous since it transforms "1 sample" x "n features" array. Can you show original shapes of `X_train`,  `X_test`, etc.?

Comment: @dkato Thank you. I've updated my post with my original code. Do you want me to post my data as well?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to check shapes of `X` and `y` by executin `X.shape` and `y.shape` just after making slice from `datasetP` dataframe. Maybe it's enough to debug.

Comment: @dkato Ok the shape of X and y are (18,) and (18, 1), respectively. Also, I updated it in the bottom of my original post.

Comment: So in this case, are you trying to train the regression model using 18 samples that have only one feature per sample?

Comment: @dkato I'm not sure what you mean by "feature". But I have 2 columns of data in my csv: Height and Points per Game. I also have 18 rows as you indicated earlier.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Then, please replace `reshape(1,-1)` to `reshape(-1, 1)` for all usages.

Comment: @dkato That worked! Thank you very much. How do I mark your answer as the answer?

Comment: I will add re-post as an answer, and please mark it:)

Comment: @dkato Ok will do. Also, can you explain the difference between `reshape(1,-1)` and `reshape(-1, 1)`? Why did the latter work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `reshape(1,-1)` to `reshape(-1, 1)` for all usages. The former transforms an array into (1 person x *n* features) and the latter does (*n* persons x 1 feature). **feature** is *hight*, in this case.

If you modified import section as below, there is no need to reshape the array since their shapes are already satisfy the form of (*n* persons x 1 feature).

```
# Import dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('NBA.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values

X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
```

In an early age of the sklearn, you can feed vector as inputs. But recently it has changed and now you need to explicitly indicate whether the vector is (*1* sample x *n* features) or (*n* samples x *1* feature) by using `reshape` or some other methods.